# statistics inequality

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $\theta$ be a discrete pararmeter and $\gamma_{n}$ be an estimator. Prove that for any $c>0$ we have that $$\text{E}[(\gamma_n-\theta)^2]
\ge\Pr[|\gamma_n-\theta|>c]\cdot c^2$$

Comment: Is the estimator unbiased?

Comment: @AndréNicolas This is irrelevant.

Comment: Got something from my answer?

Comment: And now, trying to delete your own question (with answer)? Really you are pushing all the wrong buttons...

Comment: **Stop defacing your question!**

Answer (score 1):

For **every** random variable $Y$, one has
$$
c^2\cdot\mathbf 1_{|Y|\geqslant c}\leqslant Y^2.
$$
Integrating, one gets
$$
c^2\cdot P(|Y|\geqslant c)\leqslant E(Y^2).
$$
Apply this to
$$
Y=\text{____}.
$$
And the thing [even has a name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)...