# questions on bias of estimator

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, parameter-estimation

a) Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be i.i.d Uniform$[0,\theta]$. Show that estimator $\beta(X)=max(X_{1},..,X_{n})$ is a biased estimator for $\theta$.Find an unbiased estimator, based on $\theta$. My attempt:
$E[\beta]$=$\int_{0}^{\theta}\frac{1}{\theta} .max(X_{1},..,X_{n})\,d\theta$ ,but I don't think thats right.

b)For $0<p<1$ define a random variable $X$ by $P(X=0)=p$ and $P(X=1)=1-p$. Find an unbiased estimator for $2p$. Show that there is no unbiased estimator for $p^2$. My attempt: I don't know how to 'conjure up' unbiased estimators. For the second, assume $\gamma$ is an unbiased estimator for $p^2$ and try and get a contradiction. $E(\gamma)=\gamma(0)p+\gamma(1)(1-p)=p^2$ . Is this a contradiction?

Thanks

Comment: You asked the same questions at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92418/unbiased-estimator). Please only ask questions on one SE site; if you ask a question and then decide it is better suited at another site, you can flag it and ask that it be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing together various incompatible notations and  various incompatible objects quite a lot...

For example, the expectation of the estimator is not what you write (which is absurd) but
$$
E_\theta(\beta(X))=\int_{[0,\theta]^n}\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}\,\theta^{-n}\mathrm dx_1\mathrm dx_2\ldots\mathrm dx_n.
$$
Alternatively, if one knows that the distribution of $\beta(X)$ has density $g_\theta$ on $[0,\theta]$, then
$$
E_\theta(\beta(X))=\int_0^\theta ug_\theta(u)\mathrm du.
$$
This second approach is somewhat simpler if one knows $g_\theta$. But can you identify $g_\theta$?

Re 2., one should assume that $\gamma(X)$ (not $\gamma$) is an unbiased estimator of $p$, that is, that the function $\gamma:\{0,1\}\to\mathbb R$ is independent of $p$ and that, for every $p$, 
$$
E_p(\gamma(X))=p^2.
$$
As you noted, this implies that
$$
p\gamma(0)+(1-p)\gamma(1)=p^2,
$$
that is, for every $p$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
p^2+(\gamma(1)-\gamma(0))p-\gamma(1)=0.
$$
Can you show that no function $\gamma$ achieves this?

Comment: Thanks. For the first, isnt the denisity of uniform R.V $g=\frac{1}{\theta}$? But then I get the expectation is $\frac{\theta}{2}$ and not $\theta$

Comment: Please read: g is not the density of a uniform random variable but of the maximum of n such random variables.

Comment: So how do I find g?

Comment: Can you compute $P(\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\leqslant x)$ for every $x$?

Comment: I don't understand how you get that $E_\theta(\beta(X))=\int_0^\theta ug_\theta(u)\mathrm du$. Having reviewed the definition of expectation, your first definition is correct but I can't see how this is equivalent to the above.

Comment: You doubt that if the PDF of $Z$ is $h$ then $E(Z)=\displaystyle\int zg(z)\mathrm dz$? Well, this is the very definition of expectation! (Unrelated: how come that your first question (how to find g) ceases to interest you as soon as I give you a hint to answer it?)

Comment: you misunderstand. I can't move on until I get first bit. You said that $E_\theta(\beta(X))=\int_{[0,\theta]^n}\max\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}\,\theta^{-n}dx_1\mathrm dx_2\ldots\mathrm dx_n$. I agree but then you say this is equivalent to $E_\theta(\beta(X))=\int_0^\theta ug_\theta(u)\mathrm du$. Why is this?

Comment: Because $\beta(X)$ is at the same time a unique random variable with density $g_\theta$ (hence the second formula) and a function of $n$ random variables $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ i.i.d. with density $\theta^{-1}\mathbf 1_{(0,\theta)}$ (hence the first formula).

Comment: So $g=\frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}$ and I get that the expectation is $\frac{n\theta}{n+1}$ Correct?

Comment: This is indeed $E_\theta(\beta(X))$.

Comment: Then is an unbiased estimator $\frac{(n+1)\beta}{n}$? How do I find an unbiased estimator for 2p in part b).

Comment: This is funny, you are trying to make me write piece by piece the solution you will hand back to your TA... I have another idea: **think**.

Comment: ok so an unbiased estimator for 2p satisfies $E(\alpha)=2p$ . But that gives me no way to find $\alpha$. Do I just have to guess?

Comment: Guess? Certainly not.

Comment: ok so we know $E(X)=1-p$ so is $2-2E(X)$ a suitable estimator?

Comment: Do you think it is?

Comment: Obviously. Is it?

Comment: Tell me. $ $ $ $

Comment: I answered your question 'Do you think it is? Why are you stringing me along? ( I could think of less polite ways to phrase it)?

Comment: Pease count four comments of mine backwards and refer to it.

Comment: Yes and I obeyed; I thought and came up with an answer. So what is your point?

Comment: My point is that I provided everything necessary to complete a solution and that you tried to lead me to write down a full solution ready to be handed back to your TA. This I will not do. Once again: **think**, and if you have the least idea of what is going on, you will soon reach a full solution. Unrelated: please tell me what happens there: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/734082/6179

Comment: You ask someone to think, I do so, and come up with an answer. Then you refuse to give confirmation-not much of a reward for thinking is it? Anyway, if you won't give confirmation, I can just post it again either here or somewhere else.

Comment: Please do. (Funny to see somebody complaining that they got no reward for *thinking*.)