# Find an unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, estimation

Let $X$ be an r.v defined by $P(X=0)=p$ and $P(X=1)=1-p$. Find an unbiased estimator for $2p$. My solution: $E(X)=1-p$ so $2-2E(X)$ is unbiased. Is this correct?

Comment: Wonderful! You managed to find a way to avoid to [think](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/738621/6179). One wonders what exactly is scaring you so much in the option.

Comment: @Did No my misunderstanding was cleared up. Do you tell everyone on here all they need to do is think? By the way, it is wonderful that you are following all my threads. Will I have the pleasure of you popping up everywhere?

Comment: Not all your threads, only the duplicates of questions already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.  An estimator is a statistic, but what you have written, $2 - 2 {\rm E}[X]$, is a function of a random variable.  If you have a sample $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ of IID observations from $X$, then what function of this sample will be an estimator for $2p$?

Comment: $2-2mean(x_{1},..,x_{n})$?